# Animation Container onend function is not called in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

**Flutter Doctor**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.3 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 4d7946a68d (2 months ago), 2021-03-18 17:24:33 -0700
    • Engine revision 3459eb2436
    • Dart version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Anas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Anas\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM A305F (mobile) • R58M78MVZNJ • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
    • Edge (web)        • edge        • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.37

• No issues found!
```

**Main Activity Code For Understanding**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hungers_den/ui/display_screen.dart';
import 'package:hungers_den/ui/splash_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/splashScreen',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routes: {
        '/splashScreen': (context) => SplashScreen(),
        '/displayScreen': (context) => DisplayScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Actual code where the problem is (onend function of animation container not being called)**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hungers_den/colors.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: primaryAppColor,
        body: Center(
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            width: 350,
            height: 300,
            curve: Curves.easeInOutQuint,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: RadialGradient(
              colors: [Colors.yellow, Colors.transparent],
            )),
            child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo/hungersden-logo.png",
                width: 150, height: 150),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
            onEnd: () {
              print('iam here');
              //Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/displayScreen");
            },
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

**onend function of animation container is a callback which should be called after animation completes.** i have tried this on two projects but onend print is not printed. also checked with breakpoint that it never goes to onend function idk why.

Comment: this is beacuse there is really no animation performed by your `AnimatedContainer`

Comment: yes, i totally got your point @pskink, now i used a variable and put with ternary operator in width and height, and changed it's value with setState in initState with WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_). now it's working. i will post an answer below. but can you please tell me why there's a lag in animation.

Comment: Also let me tell you what i want to do, i have an image which will be displayed as screen starts and image automatically (without button) do the animation and gets bigger with gradient as background. am i doing this the right way or should i use different kind of animation? as mentioned 5 types (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations)